# Registering a type with both EnableClassInterceptors and WithParameter

Tags: autofac

I'm having an issue with Autofac where it seems like EnableClassInterceptors is interfering with my ability to use .WithParameter(...). When the constructor is being called on Service using the code below, someString is not being populated. Notes:

- I've tried using ResolvedParameter instead, it does not help (note: my Resolved parameter still includes the name of the parameter when I tried that)
- If I remove EnableClassInterceptors and InterceptedBy, the parameter does get populated properly. This, however, isn't a valid solution as I need the interceptors.
- Re-ordering WithParameter, EnableClassInterceptors, and InterceptedBy does not help.
- Looking at [Type Interceptors](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html#class-interceptors-and-usingconstructor), specifically the "Class Interceptors and UsingConstructor" section, on docs.autofac.org, it mentions that using EnableClassInterceptors will cause ConstructUsing to fail. I think something similar might be happening with my scenario below.

Snippet of my registration code looks like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<Dependency>.As<IDependency>.InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<Service>()
    .As<IService>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("someString", "TEST"))
    .EnableClassInterceptors()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(LogExceptionsInterceptor));
```

Service's constructor looks something like this:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service(IDependency dependency, string someString)
    {
        if(dependency == null) 
            throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependency));
        if(someString == null) 
            //**throws here**
            throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(someString)); 
    }   
}
```

*[Guess]* What I'm thinking is happening is that when EnableClassInterceptors is called, a proxy class is generated with a constructor that works on top of the existing one, but the parameter names do not copy over into the proxy class/constructor.

Is this a problem? Is there a way to form the registration that allows both WithParameter and EnableClassInterceptors to be used together? Is it a bug in Autofac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct: the generated proxy class does not keep the constructor parameter names.

Currently there is no way to influence this in DynamicProxy so this is not a bug of Autofac (although this edge case currently not documented on the Autofac documentation website).

This is how your original `Service` class's parameters look like:

```
typeof(Service).GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters()
{System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[2]}
    [0]: {ConsoleApplication10.IDependency dependency}
    [1]: {System.String someString}
```

But the generated proxy does not keep the names:

```
GetType().GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters()
{System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[3]}
    [0]: {Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[] }
    [1]: {ConsoleApplication10.IDependency }
    [2]: {System.String }
```

So you have two not very robust options to workaround this limitation with `WithParameter`:

- use the `TypedParamter` with `string` as the type:

  ```
  .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "TEST"))
  ```

  However if you have multiple paramters with the same type this won't work
- use the `PositionalParameter` in this case you need to add `1` if the type is proxied

  ```
  .WithParameter(new PositionalParameter(2, "TEST"))
  ```

Another options would be to don't use a primitive string type but create a wrapper e.g. `MyServiceParameter` or create another service which can provide these `string` configuration values to your other services.

Comment: Thanks. I guess both of those two options both would work but they're a little scary since each time the class constructor params changed, I'd need to know to update the registration too, which is sort of counter-productive. (I ended up just splitting it up into a couple classes that made more sense anyway. I was still curious what the best thing to do would be if it did make sense at some point to have a situation like this.)